# when i am trying to execute aura if in component it is not working

Tags: salesforce-lightning

when i am executing my aura:if it is not working below are code and the error
can anyone help me out with this.
thanks in advance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oID0r.jpg)

[this is error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oID0r.jpg)

[this is code in component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNHdo.jpg)

[this is code in controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hjg7o.jpg)

[this is code in helper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42VUM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.checkBoxvalue">
  Your code..
 </aura:if>
```

No need to check boolean value with string.